# How to compute a channel capacity formula using Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, formula, channel, telecommunication

I am trying to compute the following formula:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4GD.jpg)

Basically, I am provided with 2 vectors which contain the values of both cj (constellation elements) and p (probability of said constellation elements). With this information, the computation of the channel capacity should be straight forward employing my code:

```
clear all;
close all;
load('parametros.mat');

%Code
figure();
plot(elements_constellation,prob);

%Energy/2D of the code
Ec = (1/length(elements_constellation))*sum(elements_constellation.^2);
Es = 2*Ec;

%Define variance values here:
sigma = 0.1;
Q_y_cj = zeros(1,length(elements_constellation));
P_Y = zeros(1,length(elements_constellation));

Q_y_cjprime = zeros(1,length(elements_constellation));
resultsintegral = zeros(1,length(elements_constellation));
cap = 0;
P_Y = 0;
figure();


x=1;
for y = 1:length(elements_constellation)

    for ii=-11:11

        Q_y_cj(x) = ((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)))*exp(-((ii-elements_constellation(y)).^2));
        x = x+1;

    end
    x=1;

   hold on
   plot(elements_constellation,Q_y_cj)

end

x=1;
figure();
for y = 1:length(elements_constellation)

    for ii=-11:11

        P_Y(x) = prob(y).*((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)))*exp(-((ii-elements_constellation(y)).^2));
        x = x+1;

    end
    x=1;

   hold on
   plot(elements_constellation,P_Y)

end
figure();
Q_y_cj_1 = zeros(1,length(elements_constellation));

P_Y = 0;
for y = 1:length(elements_constellation)
    x=1;
    for ii=-11:11

        Q_y_cj_1(x) = ((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)))*exp(-((ii-elements_constellation(y)).^2));
        for s=1:length(elements_constellation)
            P_Y = P_Y + prob(s).*((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)))*exp(-((ii-elements_constellation(s)).^2));
        end
        Q_y_cjprime(x) = Q_y_cj_1(x)*log10(Q_y_cj_1(x)/P_Y); %% These values are being overwritten
        x = x+1;
        P_Y = 0;

    end
    hold on;
    plot(elements_constellation,Q_y_cjprime);
    resultsintegral(y) = trapz(Q_y_cjprime); 
end

figure();
plot(elements_constellation,resultsintegral);

for j=1:length(prob)

    cap = cap + prob(j)*resultsintegral(j);
end
```

However, I am not convinced by the results my code generates for the channel capacity. For low values of sigma (noise variance), the capacity should increase logarithmically, but it grows exponentially when executing my algorithm.

Any help or advice on how to improve the computation of this formula would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code is quite long so in order to debug it, can you provide some example parameters `'parametros.mat'`?

Comment: I have since figured out that I was taking the completely wrong approach to solving the problem. The Y variable in the formula has to actually be defined as continuous (Y=y1:0.001:y2), instead of the discrete definition that I provided for it. Thanks for your interest though, if you still want to know how I solved it, I will gladly provide you with the code.

Comment: Well it might be a good idea to post the solution that you found as an answer, that is perfectly acceptable. This way someone else with a similar problem can find the solution here.

Comment: Very true, just haven't finished it quite yet. I will post it once I do though, thanks again!